# How to use functor as a member in class template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl, functor

I was trying to use a functor as a `std::function` object inside a class template. Below is what I have done so far.

```
//! the functor class template
template<typename T>
struct func
{
    void operator ()(T t)
    {
        std::cout << t << "\n";
    }
};

//! the class template that holds a std::function object as a member
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    std::function<void(T)> bar = func<T>();
};


int main()
{
    Foo<int> foo;
    return 0;
}
```

It was complained that

```
error: conversion from 'func<int>' to non-scalar type 'std::function<void(int)>' requested
 struct Foo
        ^
```

Is it possible to do so? How to fix it?

Comment: Isn't it just the fact that you're trying to initialize `bar` in your class declaration, while it's not an integral type?

Comment: @JorenHeit Nope, if this is c++11. E.g: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/133063/constructors-in-c11/ under: "C++11 In-Class Member Initializers". If I recall correctly since c++11 it must be only `constexpr` (but I won't bet my hand on this one).

Comment: I also don't see reasons for this code not to work - I guess this is something compiler specific

Comment: Ah right, just use initializers `{}` instead of `=`

Comment: @JorenHeit "C++11 In-Class Member Initializers"--yes,just this, I was tring to say this term..but not sure how to say it in English..

Comment: @JorenHeit Thx! your suggestion works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either make it static and initialize it outside class-scope, or initialize it in the constructor. Tested on GCC 4.7.2.

```
template<typename T>                                                                                
struct Foo                                                                                          
{                                                                                                   
    static std::function<void(T)> bar;                                                                 
};                                                                                                  

template <typename T>                                                                               
std::function<void(T)> Foo<T>::bar = func<T>();
```

**EDIT**

In C++11, you can also use brace-initialization:

```
std::function<void(T)> bar { func<T>() };
```

Comment: I tried to initialize it in the constructor. it works now. Still wondering why my code didn't compile..

Comment: @Alan.W See my edit, in case you want to remove that constructor again ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In your case std::function is optional, use direct functor itself.

```
//! the functor class template
template<typename T>
struct func
{
    void operator ()(T t)
    {
        std::cout << t << "\n";
    }
};

//! the class template that holds a std::function object as a member
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    //std::function<void(T)> bar = func<T>(); <-- **removed, because std::function isn't cheap as func<T>**.
    func<T> bar;//default initialized itself.
};


int main()
{
    Foo<int> foo;
    foo.bar(24);//prints 24.
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
 In common case, move template from struct declration to the operator, i.e. as:

```
struct func
{
   template< typename T >
   void operator()(T t ) const { std::cout << t << '\n'; }
};

struct Foo
{
    func m_func;
};

int main(){
   Foo f;
   f.m_func(24); // prints 24
   f.m_func("hello world"); // prints "hello world"
   f.m_func(3.143); // prints 3.143
   // and etc.,
};
```

in c++14, std::less<>, std::greater<>  and more other functors template keyword moved to the operator declaration, instead of struct declaration, it's help more generic comparation.

Edit2: You may use following technicus:

```
struct func{  
  template< typename T > void operator()(T t) const{ std::cout << t << '\n';} 
};

template< typename T, typename Functor> // Functor as template
struct Foo
{
    Functor m_Functor; //--> functor member
    T       m_Data; // or something else.
};

// create `makeFoo`  for auto deduced functor type.
template< typename T, typename Functor>
Foo<T,Functor>  makeFoo(Functor f, T t ) { return {f,t}; }

int print(int i, int j){ std::cout << i+j << '\n' ;}

int main()
{
    auto foo = makeFoo(24, func{} );
    // use foo

    auto foo2 = makeFoo("hello", std::bind(print, 2, _1) ); 
   // use foo2
}
```

Comment: Oh.The code above is just for demonstrating the error complained. In my real code the member `bar` need to be replaced at run time. `std::function` provides more flexibility,so that I can replace it with anything like function pointer lambda or functor. The idea of moving `template` keyword to operator declaration is great.I'll change my code as you suggested.+1 for that!

Answer (score 1):

**Different ways to use std::function in a non-static data member initializer**

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

#define ENABLE_CONVERSION 1

template<typename T>
struct func
{
    void operator ()(T t)
    {
        std::cout << "Function: " << t << "\n";
    }

    #if ENABLE_CONVERSION
    // FIX: error: conversion from ‘func<int>’ to non-scalar type
    //      ‘std::function<void(int)>’ requested
    operator std::function<void(T)> () { return std::function<void(T)>(*this); }
    #endif
};

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    std::function<void(T)> bar0 = std::function<void(T)>(func<T>());
    std::function<void(T)> bar1{func<T>()};
    // Error without ENABLE_CONVERSION
    std::function<void(T)> bar2 = func<T>();
    static std::function<void(T)> bar3;

    void operator() () {
        bar0(0);
        bar1(1);
        bar2(2);
        bar3(3);
    }
};

template<typename T>
std::function<void(T)> Foo<T>::bar3 = func<T>();

template<typename T>
void goo() {
    // This compiles without ENABLE_CONVERSION:
    // What is the difference to non-static data member initializers ?
    std::function<void(T)> g = func<T>();
    g(4);
}

int main()
{
    Foo<int> foo;
    foo();
    goo<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

**Additional question**

I tried to find differences between variable brace-or-equal-initializer
and the non-static data member brace-or-equal-initializer. I found nothing.

What is the difference between

```
std::function<void(T)> bar2 = func<T>();
```

and

```
std::function<void(T)> g = func<T>();
```

when ENABLE_CONVERSION is zero?